# forcing R PDF to new page after variable number of plots

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation

I can have an even or odd number of plots on each page, depending on the input data size/shape.

I set `par(mfrow)` to values such that it is the smallest grid possible to hold all of the plots, but now I want to make sure it moves to the next page on the next loop iteration in the case where the total number of plots ends up odd or does not fit into a grid.

How can I force a new page? Google has shown me `grid.newpage()`, but I get the error

```
> grid.newpage()
Error: could not find function "grid.newpage"
```

When I try to use it. Also, unless I am mistaken, base plotting does not use `grid` anyways so that wouldn't help me.

Comment: @baptiste yes of course.

Comment: I suspect you could just load pkg:grid and then get the desired effect with `grid.newpage()`. (Although when I tried it, the next plot was still located at the lower right.)

Comment: This works: `library(grid); grid.newpage();par(mfg=c(1,1))`

Comment: @BondedDust I _really_ doubt this mixing of grid and base graphics should be relied upon; the two systems are mostly independent, as far as I know, and their interaction seems neither documented nor trusted by their own developer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a suggested strategy: fill the empty cells with `plot.new()` until the layout is filled; next plot will automatically push a new page.

```
n = 5
rc = n2mfrow(n)
par(mfrow=rc, mar=c(0,0,0,0)) 
for(ii in seq_len(n))
    plot(rnorm(10))
for(ii in seq_len(prod(rc) - n))
    plot.new()

plot(1,1) # on its own new page
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
while(!par('page')) plot.new()
```

Comment: The first solution works. Interestingly, the second solution works on my Rstudio, but on the server where this is run I get the error `In par("page") : "page" is not a graphical parameter`

Comment: it's a fairly recent addition, IIRC. Your server is probably running an outdated version of R.

Comment: For the first solution it would probably be safer to use seq_len instead of seq.int since `seq.int(0)` has length 2. I know it's just a made up example but it doesn't hurt to think about these things.

Comment: @Dason good point, i always get those mixed up. It's actually pretty relevant here for the second loop.

Comment: I personally really like your alternative option. Thanks!